# How do you rephrase a belief that is held by all or both sides?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Mutually shared belief?
Sounds awkward though.

Comment: A *universally* held belief? But does such a thing exist?

Comment: You need to provide more information/context.  What exactly do you mean by “both sides?”. My guess is that you are talking about two people disagreeing about some ethical, political or religious matter, but sharing some relevant mutual shared beliefs.  If that is what you are after, I think the best way to express this is with the phrase ‘common ground’.  So two people might disagree violently about whether proportional representation is a good idea, but still share some common ground:  that democracy is the best form of government; that all parts of society be represented etc.

Answer (score 1):

> ## [A widely/commonly/generally held belief](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-widely-commonly-generally-held)
>
> to be believed by a lot of people
>   It was a commonly held view in those days.
>   be widely/commonly/generally held (that): It was widely held the management was out of touch with the workers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just **shared belief** works.

The reason that *mutually shared belief* sounds awkward is because it is. If a belief is shared among a group of people, then all people in the group believe it. It's redundant to add the adjective *mutually*.